# Can we make grep faster by indexing words in files?

Tags: grep, performance, search

Over a decade ago I imagined an improved version of grep that would use indexes to make recursive searching faster.  I never got around to writing it, but I wonder if somebody else did!

My original idea was:

- Keep a cached index of `word -> [line-numbers]` for each file, which would automatically update when the file size or timestamp changes.
- Use the cache for lightning-fast searches over any files with up-to-date indexes, if the expression can make use of it.
- For search expressions where the index cannot help, default to grep's usual behaviour.

Although this optimization would be limited to whole-word-searching, I thought it should be grep-compatible, so that it could be dropped in to replace `/usr/bin/grep` and help speed up various existing scripts that use grep.

There are limitations to this idea:

1. Only word-searches or searches including certain `\\<...\\>` terms would be able to benefit from the indexes, and the latter case could be complex to implement.
2. The time taken to check file stats to ensure the caches are up-to-date might make the time saved on searches minimal.

So do you think it would be worthwhile, or does point 2 make the idea worthless?

And has someone already tried this?  If so, do please share.

Comment: The related question unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40206/grep-second-time-faster asks the general question "how to speed up searches" but I am disappointed that the only answer appears to be "pre-cache the files".  Should I accept that the bottleneck is disk-access over multiple-files and not actually the cost of regexp processing, or is there a performance gain available at the CPU stage?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3086/command-line-friendly-full-text-indexing and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/69299/grep-of-many-keywords-over-many-files-speeding-it-up address indexed file searches without providing grep compatibility.

Comment: There's also this one: [Does grep use a cache to speed up the searches?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8914/does-grep-use-a-cache-to-speed-up-the-searches)

Answer (score 3):

> **Update 2019:** I found `csearch` very useful when I was running on a **HDD**, which was relatively slow at searching hundreds of small files.
>
> Now I am on a **SSD**, so reading is much faster, and I have switched to [`ripgrep`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) which automatically respects `.gitignore` and avoids the need for an indexing step.
>
> Both of them support regexp, but neither of them are 100% compatible with GNU `grep`.

## Consider Google's `csearch` for a HDD

Google's Code Search: https://github.com/google/codesearch

> Code Search is a tool for indexing and then performing regular
>   expression searches over large bodies of source code.

It does not accept the same arguments as `grep`, notably it does not accept a file list and `-r` is assumed.  However it does support a few of grep's favourite flags.

```
usage: csearch [-c] [-f fileregexp] [-h] [-i] [-l] [-n] regexp
```

So it can not act as a drop-in replacement for grep, but under certain conditions a call to grep could be converted into a call to csearch.

The regexp format (RE2, nearly PCRE) also differs from GNU grep.  For example the patterns `\<` and `\>` cannot be used for start/end word; but instead we can use `\b` for word-boundary.

### To install

On Debian and Debian clones:

```bsh
apt-get install codesearch
```

For Ubuntu 12.04 (and other versions before saucy), [download it by selecting your arch (i386/amd64) here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/codesearch) and then install it with:

```bsh
sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/codesearch_*.deb
```

### To use

```bsh
# Index the files
# It's fairly efficient but I wouldn't do it before every search
# I like to do this after switching branch
cd project
cindex .

# Search the index (case-insensitive)
csearch -i 'foo'
```

### Global or local indexes

By default Code Search will index all projects into the `~/.csearchindex` file, and **any search you run will search across all projects**.

If you want a separate index for a project, you can set the `CSEARCHINDEX` environment variable, for example:

```bsh
export CSEARCHINDEX="$HOME/.csearchindex.projectx"

# Or to store the index in the current project's root folder
export CSEARCHINDEX="$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)"/.csearchindex
```

Now `cindex` and `csearch` will use that local index file, instead of the global index.